# Watir-Webdriver - how to differentiate the buttons if there are more than one with same properties

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver

This query is based on the my previous question here [Watir-Webdriver - Unable to locate a button with id, name, text, value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32279082/watir-webdriver-unable-to-locate-a-button-with-id-name-text-value) and i got some details on how to fetch the fields through elements. But now in one of my screen i have two buttons with same class and div. So i am not able to take the one which i need. I need to get the button which has "Checking and Savings" product. Could someone help on how to get the exact button click? And my web application is developed on AnjularJS.

Here's a full div portion of the HTML from the page where the button is identified.

```
<div class="jl-layout">
    <div class="jl-layout-50-50">
        <!-- ngRepeat: entry in ctrl.vm.productSuites.entries -->
        <div style="" ng-repeat="entry in ctrl.vm.productSuites.entries" class="item product-container centered ng-scope">
            <h3 class="ng-binding">Checking and Savings</h3>
            <button type="button" tabindex="0" ng-click="ctrl.submitProductSelection(entry)" class="extra-button-padding secondary jl-button">
                <ng-transclude>
                    <span class="ng-scope">Select</span>
                </ng-transclude>
            </button>
            <div tabindex="0" role="button" ng-click="ctrl.submitProductSelection(entry)" class="mobile-click"/>
        </div>
        <!-- end ngRepeat: entry in ctrl.vm.productSuites.entries -->
        <div style="" ng-repeat="entry in ctrl.vm.productSuites.entries" class="item product-container centered ng-scope">
            <h3 class="ng-binding">Savings</h3>
            <button type="button" tabindex="0" ng-click="ctrl.submitProductSelection(entry)" class="extra-button-padding secondary jl-button">
                <ng-transclude>
                    <span class="ng-scope">Select</span>
                </ng-transclude>
            </button>
            <div tabindex="0" role="button" ng-click="ctrl.submitProductSelection(entry)" class="mobile-click"/>
        </div>
        <!-- end ngRepeat: entry in ctrl.vm.productSuites.entries -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When there are no unique properties on the element you want to interact with, you will have to look at the elements around it. In this case, it is the h3 element text that differentiates the buttons.

**Solution - Navigating DOM From Unique Element**

The simplest solution conceptually is to:

1. Get the related h3 element.
2. Navigate to the parent div element, which is also the parent of the button.
3. Get the button element in that parent div.

This would be done using:

```
product = 'Checking and Savings'
browser.h3(text: product).parent.button.click
```

**Solution - Iterating Through Groups of Related Elements**

Another approach is to iterate through each div that represents an item. For each div (item), you would check if it is the right product and then click the button.

This would be:

```
browser.divs(class: 'item').find { |div| div.h3(text: product).exists? }.button.click
```

Note that given your specific HTML snippet, this will always return the first button. The lack of closing div tag for `<div tabindex="0" role="button" ng-click="ctrl.submitProductSelection(entry)" class="mobile-click"/>`  is making everything appear in the same item div.

**Solution - Using XPath**

This is the same approach as the first solution. However, it is done using a single XPath locator. The benefit is that it is faster due to fewer method calls. However, it can be harder to read.

```
browser.button(xpath: "//h3[text()='#{product}']/../button").click
```

Comment: Thank you for providing me the solutions. I understand the logics on how to deal with the elements if its not unique. I like to follow with third solution with xpath generation as it will be uniquely represents. But as i said i am new to web atomation, so could you please help me or any place i can learn how to generate xpath for HTML elements. I tried with your third solution just by copy and paste in my code, but it throws an error.

Comment: i tried with firebug from firefox addon. but still it gives me like this "/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/button" which is different then what you have given. so please help me.

Comment: What is the error you get? It worked fine for me when I had tried it. Note that you had to define the `product` variable.

Comment: There is no single XPath for an element, which is why you see something different in Firebug. However, you have to be careful about tools that auto-generate XPaths for you. While they will be correct at the time, they over-specify the path, which makes them brittle (ie any change to the page could break the XPath).

Comment: Yes..now i got the proper navigation. i dono what happens before. Now respective button clicked and moved to next page. Thanks much for your time. And one thing please help me to learn or find how i can generate xpath for html in future. because you have given this xpath line "b.button(xpath: "//h3[text()='Checking and Savings']/../button").click" and i used it. but what actually this '/../button' part does i am not sure.

Comment: I would start by going through some examples - eg [Microsoft has a page with a bunch of examples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Then you can build on that as you encounter new problems.

Comment: Ok Thanks Much. I will look into it.